# DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize content-type: text/plain

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am new to Azure functions and I have created a `Timer Trigger` Azure Function to retrieve the list of repositories from `Azure Container Registry` using `Azure Python SDK v3.6`.

This code is executed properly in my local `VS Code` setup but when I deploy it in Azure and execute I get a `DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize content-type: text/plain` error.

Here is a summary of what I tried till now:

```
import azure.functions as func
from azure.containerregistry import ContainerRegistryClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

container_registry_client = ContainerRegistryClient(
    account_url,
    DefaultAzureCredential()
    # DefaultAzureCredential(logging_enable=True)
)

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    logging.info("============================Start=================================")
    # Here I am able to print the container registry client which is not null, 
    # So I assume my azure function is able to connect with my ACR
    logging.info(dir(container_registry_client)) 
    # Nothing is getting printed here onwards, so I assume some issues here or in For loop
    repository_names = container_registry_client.list_repository_names()
    
    for repository_name in repository_names:
        logging.info("ACR Repository Names: " + str(repository_name))
    
    logging.info("============================End=================================")
```

Full Error stack:

```
Ran into a deserialization error. Ignoring since this is failsafe deserialization Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1501, in failsafe_deserialize return self(target_obj, data, content_type=content_type) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1367, in __call__ data = self._unpack_content(response_data, content_type) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1541, in _unpack_content raw_data.headers File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/universal.py", line 226, in deserialize_from_http_generics return cls.deserialize_from_text(body_bytes, content_type) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/universal.py", line 203, in deserialize_from_text raise DeserializationError("Cannot deserialize content-type: {}".format(content_type)) msrest.exceptions.DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize content-type: text/plain
```

Comment: Could you please check if you have right permissions to retrieve the list of repositories

Comment: I created this registry and all the repositories within it, so i do have permissions to list them as well